# How can i write which element corresponds to which score in 2 different arrays?

Tags: c#, sorting, multidimensional-array, text-files, calculation

I have got 25 elements in my txt file. My code calculates their scores according to answer key. Then i would like to sort them without using sort.Array etc. I made it and a assigned them another array which is name is result. Now i would like to write the elements number according to order of result array

. For example the element 101' score 78. The element 105' s score is 25.
The result array sort them: 78-25
i would like to sort them : 101-105
my code is:

```
//arranging results according to their values
int temp = 0;
int[] elm = new int[result.Length];

for (int i = 0; i <= result.Length-1 ; i++)
{
    
    for (int j = i+1 ; j < result.Length; j++)
    {
        if (result[i] < result[j])
        {
            temp = result[i];
            result[i] = result[j];
            result[j] = temp;
        }
        elm[j] = Convert.ToInt16(row[i,0]);
    }
    ;
    
}
```

Comment: I find what you're asking for as a bit unclear. Consider showing us the contents of the text file and perhaps more code. You would also gain from learning to use LINQ.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.